# mysqli not found when running on server

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

When I run my app on local host, I don't have any trouble, but when it is running on heroku I get this error:
Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /app/www/db.php on line 13

I ran this code to check it:

```
if (!function_exists('mysqli_init') && !extension_loaded('mysqli')) {

    echo 'We don\'t have mysqli!!!';

} else {

    echo 'Phew we have it!';

}
```

When I run this on localhost I get "Phew we have it!" but when I run it on heroku I get "We don't have mysqli!!!".
I have no idea what the problem is, so any help would be great.

Comment: The problem is that the heroku server doesn't have mysqli, what version of php is it runnning?

Answer (score 3):

According to a [blogger in 2011](http://dracossoftware.blogspot.com/2011/10/bye-bye-heroku-phpfog-phail-hello-my.html), heroku does not support the `mysqli` class.  It does [support postgres](http://postgres.heroku.com/), but I am not sure if the PHP installation includes support for postgres.  [This blogger](http://log.demaree.me/post/14996591419/heroku-supports-php-yay-yes-yay) indicates that it does.

Someone more familiar with heroku could possibly give you a better answer.

Comment: Have an upvote good friend, hopefully it'll soften the blow of never getting this answer accepted :}

Answer (score 0):

[PHP on Heroku, again](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/php-on-heroku-again/) walks you through what it takes to customize Heroku's default PHP setup, including installing additional modules.

There's a [github repo](https://github.com/wuputah/heroku-libraries/tree/master/php) with a few modules that have been compiled and published already, including MySQLi.